# Tableau TDE or connect to files directly?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a personal license for Tableau. I am using it to connect to .csv and .xlsx files currently but am running into some issues.

1) The .csv files are massive (10+ gig)
2) The Excel files are starting to reach the 1mil row limit
3) I need to add certain columns to the .csv files sometimes (like unique ID and a few formulas) which means that I need to open sections of them in Excel, modify what I need to, then save a new file

Would it be better to create an extract for each of these files and then connect the Tableau Workbook to the extract instead of the file? Currently I am connected directly to files and then extract data from there and refresh everyday.

Comment: "I am connected directly to files and then extract data from there and refresh everyday.". This statement implies that you are already using extract files, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: My dashboards all point to excel or csv files. They each individually extract the data. I'm wonder if I should create an extract for each file,  maintain those extracts,  and point my workbooks to the extracts rather than the individual files

Comment: If the question is "Will I see better performance on 10+ gig files using extracts instead of text files?", then the answer is almost certainly yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about others, but I'm using that exactly guideline. I'll have some Workbooks that will simply serve to extract data from some datasource (be it SQL, xlsx, csv, mdb, or any other), and all analysis will be performed in other Workbooks, that'll connect only to tdes

The advantages are:

1) Whenever you need to update a data source, you'll need to only update once (and replace the tde file) and all your workbooks will be up to date. If you connect to the same data source and extract to different tde files, you'll have to extract to all those different tde files (and worry about having updated the extract in that specific Workbook). And even if you extract to the same tde (which doesn't make much sense), it can be confusing (am I connected to the tde or to the file? Does the extract I made in the other workbook updated this one too? Well, yes it did, but it can be confusing)

2) You don't have to worry about replacing a datasource, especially when it's a csv, xlsx or mdb file. You can keep many different versions of those files, and choose which one is the best one. For instance, I'll have table_v1.mdb, table_v2.mdb, ..., and a single table_v1.tde, which will be the extract of one of those mdb files. And I still have the previous versions in case I need them.

3) When you have a SQL connection, or anything that is not a file (csv, xlsx, mdb), extracts are very handy for basically the same reasons above, with (at least) one upside. You don't need to connect to a server every time you want to perform an analysis. That means you can do everything offline, and the person using Tableau doesn't need to have access to the SQL table (or any other source).

One good practice is always keeping a back-up when updating a tde (because, well, shit happens)

Answer (score 1):

10 gig csv, wow. Yes, you should absolutely use a data extract, that would be much quicker. For that much data you could look at other connections such as MS Access or a SQL instance.

If your data have that many rows, I would try to set up a small MySQL instance on your local machine and keep the data there instead. You would be able to connect Tableau directly to the MySQL instance and would be able to easily edit the source data.